Travelling from India to Bali [Transit Visa and Luggage]
I am planning to travel from India to Bali, with a Check-in-baggage too.
Taking a flight from India to Kuala Lumpur
AirAsia X D7-182
3H Layover
From Kuala Lumpur to Bali
AirAsia AK-376.
I want to confirm that would I require a transit visa, and would I need to scan the luggage again or the airline will connect that?
Because I'm purchasing the extra luggage and if the airline doesn't connects, I would need to pay again on scanning it.

This depends largely on how you book the ticket: Air Asia is mainly a point-to-point carrier but does offer so-called "Fly Thru" itineraries where the manage the connection details for you: See https://www.airasia.com/aa/campaign/en/gb/philippines-fly-thru.html for details
If you do NOT have a Fly Thru ticket, you need proper entry documentation for Malaysia, you need to pass immigration, you need to collect your bags, check them in again, pay twice for extra luggage and pass through security again.
If you HAVE a Fly Thru ticket, I suggest carefully reading the exact rules and terms of your specific ticket. Exact rules and fees can vary with the specific route.

KL airport has option to connect the bags from airside. You can approach a transfer counter airside and they will connect your bags, without clearing immigration and checking again.
